# How did people cut their nails in the past?

Tags: ancient-history, everyday-life

How did people cut their toe and fingernails before we got nail clippers after the industrial revolution?

Would they have had a fair amount of ingrown toenails, especially in the colder regions where feet had to be kept wrapped up?

Comment: knives, files. biting. wear and tear.

Comment: I take it you saw [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nail_clipper#mediaviewer/File:Magdalenenberg_cut_and_shave.jpg), which Wikipedia claims is a nail cutter from the Hallstatt culture?

Comment: ingrown toenails are not caused by failing to cut your toenails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a paring knife. That's why nail parings are called, well, nail parings.

Also, there were nippers similar to modern yarn cutters which were in common use since Roman times. Yarn cutters look like this:

[image]

Comment: And how did they cut their nails before iron and steel became common?

Comment: @Alex By using bronze knives?

Comment: perhaps. And in the Stone age with stone knives:-) Have to tried to cut your nails with a KNIFE?

Comment: @Alex cutting your nails with a knife isnt that hard, done it a couple times camping, not proficient at it so i cant make nice even cuts, but i imagine with practice it wouldn't be hard, and for pre metal, i assume they just bit their nails, or wear and tear.

Comment: @Himarm: you bet:-) I've even heard of people shaving with an ax...

Comment: Flint. Obsidian. The latter is sharper than any steel knife, the former as sharp as a stainless knife.

Answer (score 4):

Scraping the tip of your nails across a pocket knife blade. My grandfather does it all the time. It's similar to how some nail files work.